# I want to install composer require laravelista/comments but I face with error

Tags: comments, laravel-9

**I have php verison "PHP 8.1.6", composer version "2.2.13" and laravel version"9.25.1"**

During Installing the following comments package

**composer require laravelista/comments**

By runing the above command it show me the following error, Please guide me how to fix.

**Error:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\pixel>composer require laravelista/comments
```

Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^4.5 for laravelista/comments
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravelista/comments
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravelista/comments ^4.5 -> satisfiable by laravelista/comments[4.5.0].
- laravelista/comments 4.5.0 requires illuminate/database ^8.0 -> found illuminate/database[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravelista/comments:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravelista/comments:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfoKo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below command:

```
composer require laravelista/comments --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Not working and same issue